# ng2-charts not show on client side while using in angular 2.0.0-beta-17

Tags: typescript, angular, ng2-charts

I am trying to use `ng2-charts` in angular 2 app but facing issues

## app.ts

```
 import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

    import {CHART_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';

    @Component({
        selector: 'my-app',
        template:

     `

<base-chart class="chart"
           [data]="barChartData"
           [labels]="barChartLabels"
           [options]="barChartOptions"
           [series]="barChartSeries"
           [legend]="barChartLegend"
           [chartType]="barChartType"
           (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
           (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
</base-chart>
`
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor() {
        console.log('bar demo');
    }

    private barChartOptions = {
        scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
        responsive: true,
        multiTooltipTemplate: '<%if (datasetLabel){%><%=datasetLabel %>: <%}%><%= value %>'
    };
    private barChartLabels = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
    private barChartSeries = ['Series A', 'Series B'];
    public barChartType = 'Bar';
    private barChartLegend: boolean = true;

    private barChartData = [
        [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
        [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
    ];

    // events
    chartClicked(e: any) {
        console.log(e);
    }
    chartHovered(e: any) {
        console.log(e);
    }

}
```

### issue nothing display

[image]

Comment: missing "directives: [CHART_DIRECTIVES]" in @Component({...})?

Comment: i added  directives: [CHART_DIRECTIVES] but new error occur...
Error...
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
angular2-polyfills.js:349 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:50944/ng2-charts/ng2-charts(…)

Comment: import {CHART_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';
question updated

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a map in your `SystemJS` configuration properties, otherwise SystemJS has no idea where to load it from:

```
System.config({
  map: {
     'ng2-charts': 'node_modules/ng2-charts'
  },
  //...
});
```

Comment: after adding the map property  I have encounter with these errors...
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
angular2-polyfills.js:349 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:50944/node_modules/ng2-charts/ng2-charts(…)ZoneDelegate.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:349
http://localhost:50944/favicon.ico Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: hi i use webpack instead of systemjs how configure ?

Comment: @ELmissaouihabib add in your webpack config `resolve.alias` this: `'ng2-charts': 'node_modules/ng2-charts'`